# Iterative programming on an ordered spark stream using Java in Spark Streaming?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there anyway in spark streaming to keep data across multiple micro-batches of a sorted dstream, where the stream is sorted using timestamps? (Assuming monotonically arriving data)
Can anyone make suggestions on how to keep data across iterations where each iteration is an RDD being processed in JavaDStream?

**What does iteration mean?**

I first sort the dstream using timestamps, assuming that data has arrived in a monotonically increasing timestamp (no out-of-order).

I need a global HashMap X, which I would like to be updated using values with timestamp "t1", and then subsequently "t1+1". Since the state of X itself impacts the calculations it needs to be a linear operation. Hence operation at "t1+1" depends on HashMap X, which depends on data at and before "t1".

**Application**

This is especially the case when one is trying to update a model or compare two sets of RDD's, or keep a global history of certain events etc which will impact operations in future iterations?

I would like to keep some accumulated history to make calculations.. not the entire dataset, but persist certain events which can be used in future DStream RDDs?

Comment: Are you asking how to persist to HDFS ?

Comment: @jaco0646  i want to keep it in an in memory state which i can use in the future iterations to make some decision. For example it might be possible to do it using foreachRDD, but i do not know how

Answer (score 1):

`UpdateStateByKey` does precisely that: it enables you to define some state, as well as a function to update it based on each RDD in your stream. This is the typical way to accumulate historical computations over time.

From the doc:

> The updateStateByKey operation allows you to maintain arbitrary state while continuously updating it with new information. To use this, you will have to do two steps.
>
> 1. Define the state - The state can be of arbitrary data type.
> 2. Define the state update function - Specify with a function how to update the state using the previous state and the new values from input stream.

More info here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#updatestatebykey-operation

If this does not cut it or you need more flexibility, you can always store to a key-value store explicitly like Cassandra (cf Cassandra connector: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), although this option is typically slower since it systematically involves network transfer at every lookup..

Comment: thanks for the cassandra suggestion. Please look at the iterative part of the question as well. I would like to go iteratively over objects in a sorted stream, where I am able to save some data "state" across multiple iterations.

Comment: Please look at my updated question. Let me know if you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. `UpdateStateByKey` _is_, in some sense, a global HashMap. The key of the global HashMap are the key of the updateStateByKey. All you have to do is figure out which row of the RDD  will impact which (key, value) of the "global HashMap" => call `keyBy()` based on that decision, then just call updateStateByKey while providing a function to update the content of the map based on previous content and the data in the current RDD. Does this approach fit in your problem?

Comment: not quite... Imagine the operation to be iterative on a sorted stream by timestamps. Hence the global hashmap's update operation on data at time (t+1), depends on data at time (t) as well as the current state of the hashmap. I really need the solution to be iterative, I've tried to see how I can do this using foreach and global updates.

Comment: For the iterations, keep in mind that spark streaming is a distributed framework, and your input data typically is as well (e.g. Kafka) => order of operation is typically not guaranteed: it all happens in parallel in plenty of distributed slaves, some slower/faster than others due to plenty of runtime reasons, some operations crashing and being restarted else where => most of the time we try to define operation that do not depend on ordered processing of data.

Comment: I understand, however I need to do ordered iterative processing. As I said, I have sorted the data using timestamps as a key first. This is after several map-reduce operations, which did work. However, now I need to do an iterative operation sequentially on the data. It's ok that this is not parallelized across multiple workers because it's not naturally parallel.